# Angular factory access private functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have an Angular factory that I use the revealing module pattern to expose a service interface.  The factory used other injected dependencies to support the public service that are not included in the public service itself.  I understand why the code below is broken, but what I'm asking is if there is a standard patter to accomplish this?  I'm not having much luck figuring out the correct pattern to give me access to the private members/functions when the public service is invoked.  Any pointers are appreciated.  In the code below, if a controller calls `myfactory.initData();`, the private functions and vars are not accessible.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('myFactory', ['common', 'config', myFactory]);

    function myFactory(common, config) {       
        var data = { cogs: [], widgets: [] };
        var dep = config.dependency;

        // Return this factory service definition
        var service = {
            data: data,            
            initData: initData,
            reset: reset            
        };   
        return service;  

        function initData(forceRefresh) {
            _private1(); // out of scope, not part of returned service
            _private2(); // out of scope, not part of returned service
        }        

        function _private1() {
            // get cogs, from non-exposed private
            dep.f1();
        }

        function _private1() {
            // get cogs, from non-exposed private
            dep.f2();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: They're private for a reason.  You should be able to test it from the public interface.  There's no way to access those privates.

Comment: I don't see why it is broken? If you need access to those functions don't make them private.

Comment: I agree with both Juan and MinusFour... It's not broken as stated, and they are private for a reason.  The reason is I don't want to expose the internals of the service to consumers of the service, but I may need to have reusable pieces of login with the service that the public API can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access your private functions because you don't have any references to them in scope - save them into a variable to keep them in scope:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('myFactory', ['common', 'config', myFactory]);

    function myFactory(common, config) {       
        var data = { cogs: [], widgets: [] };
        var dep = config.dependency; 

        var _private1 = function() {
            // get cogs, from non-exposed private
            dep.f1();
        }

        var _private1 = function() {
            // get cogs, from non-exposed private
            dep.f2();
        }

        // Return this factory service definition
        var service = {
            data: data,            
            initData: initData,
            reset: reset            
        };   
        return service; 

        function initData(forceRefresh) {
            _private1(); // out of scope, not part of returned service
            _private2(); // out of scope, not part of returned service
        }  
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks @lightswitch05, I studied up some more and played around until I for it the way I wanted thanks to your help.  Much appreciated!  [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pseabury/f3w1Lqeu/)